# difference between Business Rules Management System and Business Process Management Suite

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I am new to this tool, and i had started working with BRMS to created some simple rules. Now while working i got confused with BRMS and BPM Suite.
Can anyone tell me the basic difference between them.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. In those questions learn how to properly provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can find a simple comparison [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite/6.4/paged/development-guide/chapter-2-red-hatjboss-brms-and-red-hat-jboss-bpm-suite-architecture). Basically, JBoss BRMS is a subset of JBoss BPM Suite.

BRMS includes Business Rules Engine (Drools), Business Resource Planner (OptaPlanner), Business Central (Drools Workbench), and Realtime Decision Server (KIE Server). These tools support business rules creation and execution as well as solving optimization problems.

BPM Suite includes everything that is in BRMS but in addition to it, there is also Execution Engine (jBPM), Business Central (KIE Workbench), Process Execution Server (KIE Server), and Business Activity Monitoring Dashboards (Dashbuilder). These tools offer complete BPM solution including business process modelling, execution, and monitoring.